# I need to execute some code only for RCP not For RAP how can i do that

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-rap

I am working on eclipse RCP/RAP single sourcing. 
i need to execute some code in `resotreState()` and `saveState()` method of `ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor` class that is needed only for RCP but not for RAP. What is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

If the code that should only execute in RCP compiles on both platforms then you can query `SWT#getPlatform()` like this:

```java
if( !SWT.getPlatform().startsWith( "rap" ) ) {
  // execute RCP code
}
```

If the RCP code uses API that is not available on both platforms, then I recommend to *extract* the code into a fragment and only deploy that fragment with the RCP applications. Search for 'rap single sourcing' for more on that.

Comment: Please see the following code :   `@Override`
 `public IStatus saveState(IMemento memento) {`   
  `TerminalCompatibility.saveState(memento);`
  `ServerStorageController.getInstance().saveState(memento);`
  `return super.saveState(memento);`
 `} ` -- this code is dependent on  IMemento . Is it posible i can move this code to a RCP specific fragment. i do not want to write empty compatibility classes.

Comment: `IMemento` is available on both platforms so that you can use the first approach and guard the code that saves state with an if condition.